# Python: Mock AWS with Click

Tags: python-3.x, python-click, pytest-mock

I have a click cli app and I am trying to mock AWS SSM Parameter Store, but runner.invoke is not returning the expected results.

This is `test_demo.py`:

```
from click.testing import CliRunner

import os
import boto3
from moto import mock_ssm
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='package')
def aws_credentials():
    """Mocked AWS Credentials for moto."""
    os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-west-2'


@pytest.fixture(scope='package')
def ssm(aws_credentials):
    with mock_ssm():
        yield boto3.client('ssm')


def test_get_mock_ssm(ssm):
    # We need to create the ssm entry first since this is all in Moto's 'virtual' AWS account
    ssm.put_parameter(
        Name='test',
        Description='name',
        Value='text',
        Type='String',
        Overwrite=True,
        Tier='Standard',
        DataType='text'
    )
    out = ssm.get_parameter(Name='test')
    print('without cli')
    print(out)
    from src.cli import entrypoint
    runner = CliRunner()
    response = runner.invoke(entrypoint, ["get", "--name", "test"])
    print('with cli')
    print(response)
    assert response.exit_code == 0
```

The results of the test are:

```
without cli
{'Parameter': {'Name': 'test', 'Type': 'String', 'Value': 'text', 'Version': 1, 'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 31, 9, 3, 21, 920000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ARN': 'arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:1234567890:parameter/test'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'amazon.com'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

with cli
<Result okay>
PASSED
```

I expect the out of the cli to be same as withoutcli.

click code:

```
import click

import manage_secrets


@click.group()
def entrypoint():
    pass


@entrypoint.command()
@click.option('--name', required=True,
              help='Name of parameter to get value from SSM')
def get(name):
    """get secrets"""
    click.echo("getting value of: {0}" .format(name))
    print(manage_secrets.get_value_from_parameter_store(name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    entrypoint()
```

manage_secrets code:

```
import boto3

parameter_name = None


def get_value_from_parameter_store(name):
    client = boto3.client('ssm')
    try:
        parameter = client.get_parameter(Name=name, WithDecryption=True)
        return parameter
    except client.exceptions.ParameterNotFound:
        print("parameter not found")
```

I have added a return and its just default, not parsing and I think it is the same for ssm.get_parameter. I am not sure what I am missing. Any pointers or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My result was ok, I need to get the `response.output` from the test.

This helped: https://gist.github.com/lbillingham/6412cdc19f9a44901b03841e0443fbf7